# The fairness of the Coin Toss.

Tags: probability

A and B each have a coin and toss each. And observe the sequence according to the respective coins. In other words, A and B only need to observe the result of their tosses. In addition, A and B are operated at the same time. If A observes "heads-tails-heads" first, then A wins. If B observes "heads-tails-heads" first, then B wins. Is this game fair?

Comment: Who tosses first?  What does "front-reverse-front" mean?  Is A observing only his own coin tosses?  Is B observing his own coin tosses?  Whoever tosses first, do the players then alternate?  Assuming that A tosses first, and assuming that they alternate, if A observes **his** sequence on the $n$-th throw, and **then** B also observes **his** sequence on the $n$-th throw, is it a tie or does A win.  Based on your answer here, it seems clear that either A has the advantage because he tosses first, or it is 50-50, re B can **come from behind**.

Comment: I'm going to guess that they toss simultaneously; that front & reverse mean heads and tails; that each observes only her own tosses. But stoch should clarify.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you! I'm sorry that my description is not clear enough, your guess is correct.

Comment: @user2661923 I'm very sorry that my description is not clear. Both A and B observe the results of their own tosses. There is no process of the players alternation.

Comment: "There is no process of the players alternation."  What does this mean.  If their flipping is **not synchronized**, suppose that B has arthritis, so A can flip twice as fast?  Doesn't A then have an overwhelming advantage.  And vice-versa, suppose that A has arthritis.

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you for your patience. I mean that A and B are tosses at the same time. Assuming that A and B's physical conditions are exactly the same. If someone can flip twice as fast, then he can easily gain an advantage in this game. This will make the problem more complicated.

Comment: If A and B have *synchronized* tosses, isn't the problem **symmetrical**.  How could A have an advantage over B, or vice-versa?

Comment: @user2661923 When the operations are synchronized, the game is fair. Will this game be unfair when only asynchronous or when the player's physical condition is different?

Comment: It would have to be unfair then, wouldn't it.  If $m > n$ and in a fixed length of time, A flips $m$ times and B only flips $n$ times, then A has to have the advantage.  For example, if A *totally strikes out* in his first $(m-n)$ flips, then the game becomes fair.  Since A might not strike out in his first $(m-n)$ flips, he has the advantage.

Comment: I think I understand. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The game would be **a lot** more interesting if A and B had different sequences to achieve. For instance, if A wins when they achieve heads-heads-heads, and B wins when they achieve heads-tails-heads.

Answer (score 0):

The game you describe is completely symmetrical, therefore both players have the same probability of winning.

Note that a draw is possible too, although pretty unlikely. It's a bit of a pain to calculate exactly, but I would be surprised if the probability of a draw were higher than 1/32.

However, the game becomes much more interesting if you change it ever-so-slightly and give players A and B two different sequences to achieve. Consider the following game:

> A and B each have a coin and toss each. And observe the sequence according to the respective coins. In other words, A and B only need to observe the result of their tosses. In addition, A and B are operated at the same time. If A observes ***heads-heads-heads*** first, then A wins. If B observes ***heads-tails-heads*** first, then B wins. Is this game fair?

Now the game is very slightly asymmetrical.

It would be tempting to conclude hastily that the game is still "symmetrical enough" and thus that A and B have equal probabilities of winning.

However, this is too simplistic.

It is true that A and B are both trying to achieve a particular sequence of length 3. However, which particular sequence they are trying to achieve does matter. Perhaps counterintuitively, not all sequences are as easy to achieve.

When throwing a coin three times in a row, of course, the probability of achieving a particular sequence is exactly 1/8, no matter which particular sequence we are trying to achieve. But it is not what is happening here. When a player tosses the coin one more time, the next sequence-of-three they observe overlaps with the previous sequence-of-three they have just observed, and this impacts the conditional probability of winning on the next toss.

Imagine that the game has already been going on for n rounds, where n is some integer greater than 2. Then when we ask "what is the probability that B achieves their sequence on the next toss?", what we are interested in is not the general probability of achieving that particular sequence in three tosses when starting from nothing, but instead, we are interested in the *conditional probability* of achieving that sequence on the (n+1)th toss, *knowing that* we haven't achieved that sequence on the nth toss. This conditional probability might deviate slightly from the general 1/8 probability.

When B tosses for the (n+1)th time, we know that their (n-2, n-1, n) tosses were **not** (heads, tails, heads), otherwise they would have won already. Because of this observation, the conditional probability that their (n-1, n) tosses were (tails, heads) is only 1/7 instead of 1/4, and the probabilities that those were (heads, tails), (heads, heads) or (tails, tails) are 2/7, 2/7, 2/7 respectively instead of 1/4, 1/4, 1/4 respectively as we might have wrongly thought. Thus the probability of B winning on the (n+1)th toss is $2/7 \times 1/2 = 1/7$, which is **slightly higher** than the naive $1/8$ that we might have wrongly thought.

Similarly, when A tosses for the (n+1)th time, we know that their (n-2, n-1, n) tosses were **not** (heads, heads, heads). Because of this observation, the probability that their (n-1, n) tosses were (heads, heads) is only 1/7 instead of 1/4, and the probabilities that those were (heads, tails), (tails, heads) or (tails, tails) are 2/7, 2/7, 2/7 respectively instead of 1/4, 1/4, 1/4 respectively as we might have wrongly thought. Thus the probability of A winning on the (n+1)th toss is $1/7 \times 1/2 = 1/14$, which is **much lower** than the naive $1/8$ that we might have wrongly thought.

As a conclusion, B is much more likely than A of winning this game.